# Wordpress theme development: variables from included files are blank when being used in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

at the top of my functions.php I included another PHP file like the example below:

```
<?php  
  //file.php
  $var1 = "abc";
  $var2 = "123"

 ?>
```

In functions.php:

```php
<?php   
include 'file.php';

// echoing or using the variable in functions.php returns a blank value
?>
```

In functions.php I included file.php but when I tried to echo $var1 it's completely blank. Why does it not print "abc"?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the right path to the file you want to include.
for example:

```
include get_theme_file_path( '/subdir/filename.php' );
```

Comment: @Micheal Mulik it seems to be in the correct path but my variable is still not accessible in functions.php. I even tried storing my variable in environment variables and it still doesn't show any data.

Comment: If you want it to be in the function.php, then you may use the init function

add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_vars' );
 
function add_custom_vars() {
     if( !isset( $specialVar ) ) {
         $specialVar = 'custom';
     }
}

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add semicolon at the end of the $var2. Please replace with below code.

```
<?php  
  //file.php
  $var1 = "abc";
  $var2 = "123";
 ?>
```

Also, please make sure that both the files in the same folder. If both he files in different folders, then please use below code to include the file:

```
require get_template_directory() . '/folder-name/file.php';
```